# In what case is the insertion order altered when adding new key value pair in HashMap?

Tags: java

Help me understand how the insertion order work here.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
            hashMap.put(1, "Amrendra");
            hashMap.put(10, "Joe");
            hashMap.put(2, "Aakash");
            System.out.println(hashMap);
            
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            linkedHashMap.put(1, "Amrendra");
            linkedHashMap.put(10, "Joe");
            linkedHashMap.put(2, "Aakash");
            System.out.println(linkedHashMap);
```

Comment: Do you mean the iteration order? The insertion order is just the order in which you put things into the map.

Comment: Even when iterating, both hashSet and linkedHashSet objects iterated the same way. I used .entrySet().iterator() in both the objects to achieve that. Why is there no difference in the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` does not maintain insertion order, while using `iterator` you can observe that, meanwhile `LinkedHashMap` takes extra memory to maintain insertion order while iterating. `LinkedHashMap` uses `DoublyLinkedList` to preserve the order, you can also choose to preserve access order (or) insertion order using one of `LinkedHashMap` constructor.

Access order is least recently used first. Insertion order on other hand works like `FIFO`.

**UPDATE**

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, "Amrendra");
hashMap.put(10, "Joe");
hashMap.put(2, "Aakash");
hashMap.put(5, "Android");
System.out.println("HashMap: "+hashMap);

hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1, "Amrendra");
hashMap.put(10, "Joe");
hashMap.put(2, "Aakash");
hashMap.put(5, "Android");
System.out.println("LinkedHashMap: " + hashMap);
```

The above snipped will produce following output
[image]

By output, you can clearly depict that in `HashMap`, `Joe` was inserted before `Akash`, but while retrieving you get `Akash` before `Joe`, where as in `LinkedHashMap` the insertion order is maintained as is.

Comment: While iterating through the code above, both hashMap and linkedHashMap objects iterated in the same way. I used obj.entrySet().iterator() in both cases. An example on how hashMap doesn't maintain insertion order will definitely help. Can you please clarify a little more?

Comment: Updated post to answer your question with example

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` doesn't keep track of insertion order. When you iterate over the entries of a `HashMap`, the iteration order is implementation specific. The current implementation iterates over the bins of the `HashMap`, first returning the entries in bin 0, then the entries in bin 1, and so on...

Therefore the iteration order you are seeing for `HashMap` depends on the `hashCode` of the keys, which determines the bins the entries are put into.

The second key you put in the `HashMap` - `10` - was assigned to a bin with a higher index than the bin of the third key (`2`), which is why `10` is printed last when the `HashMap` is iterated.

When you use a `LinkedHashMap`, the insertion order is maintained, and when you iterate over the entries, you get them in the same order the keys were added to the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by rajan.kali. Simply use HashMap when order does not matter (which it in most cases doesn't) and LinkedHashMap in the rare cases where it does.

Also, make it a habit to define variables using an interfaces if possible (generally, if you only call the methods defined in Map, define the variable as a Map, there is most often no need to explicitly indicate that eg a Map is a HashMap):

```
Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```